# Multiple word search feature HTML list filter

Tags: javascript, html, search, split, html-lists

I have a search feature which uses JavaScript to filter a html list.

All list items are hidden by default but show if the user inputs the right keywords.

At the moment the search only returns items which match the input exactly.

If a word is missed, additional word added or order of words differ, the result isn’t shown.

I’d like the user to be able to search multiple words, and if one or more of the words match, the result is shown.

It should not matter which order the user inputs the words.

For example, searching **‘VAUXHALL CORSA DIESEL’** would return the list item, **‘BLUE VAUXHALL CORSA 1.6L DIESEL.’**

Searching **‘DIESEL VAUXHALL’** would also return the same list item.

I figured this could be done by incorporating .split(“ ”), however I am unsure at what point in the code it is needed.

I’ve tried a few configurations to no avail.

I’m very new to coding!

I’ve added the current script.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  var filter = document.getElementById("filter"),
    list = document.querySelectorAll(".list li");
  filter.onkeyup = () => {
    let search = filter.value.toLowerCase();
    for (let i of list) {
      let item = i.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      if (item.indexOf(search) == -1) {
        i.classList.add("hide");
      } else {
        i.classList.remove("hide");
        if (filter.value.length == 0) {
          i.classList.add("hide");
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML, CSS and an example list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guessed some HTML

This does what you ask using `.every` and `.includes`

I also use on input instead since the user can paste into the field
Lastly I simplified the hiding

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const list = document.querySelector(".list")
  filter = document.getElementById("filter"),
    lis = [...list.querySelectorAll("li")]; // spread to use map and sort
  filter.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let search = filter.value.toLowerCase().split(/\W+/);
    lis.forEach(li => {
      if (search.length === 0) {
        li.hidden = true;
        li.dataset.rank = 0;
        return
      }
      let items = li.textContent.toLowerCase().split(/\W+/)
      li.hidden = !search.every(flt => items.includes(flt))
      li.dataset.rank = search.filter(flt => items.includes(flt)); // how many
    });
    lis.sort((a, b) => a.dataset.rank - b.dataset.rank).forEach(li => list.append(li))
  });
});
```

```html
For example, searching ‘VAUXHALL CORSA DIESEL’ would return the list item, Searching ‘DIESEL VAUXHALL’ would also return the same list item.
<hr/>
<input type="text" id="filter" />
<ul class="list">
  <li>BLUE VAUXHALL CORSA 1.6L DIESEL</li>
  <li>RED DIESEL</li>
  <li>GREEN VAUXHALL ASTRA 1.6L PETROL</li>
  <li>RED VAUXHALL CORSA 1.6L DIESEL</li>
  <li>RED VAUXHALL CORSA 1.6L PETROL</li>
  <li>RED VAUXHALL ASTRA 1.6L PETROL</li>
  <li>RED VAUXHALL ASTRA 1.6L DIESEL</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I added ranking - it would be clearer with more data

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the search with empty space.

For example

```
let searchKeywords = filter.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

and with `every` array function check the item if `contains` every keyword in the search.

Full example of code.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  var filter = document.getElementById("filter"),
    list = document.querySelectorAll(".list li");
  filter.onkeyup = () => {
    let searchKeywords = filter.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (let i of list) {
      let item = i.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      if (searchKeywords.every(word => item.includes(word))) {
        i.classList.add("hide");
      } else {
        i.classList.remove("hide");
        if (filter.value.length == 0) {
          i.classList.add("hide");
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan `some` will output the wrong value, In your example, if you search "VAUXHALL blablabla" this will show the two items, but this is not correct, I think the OP ask to check the all keywords.